# Calling PowerShell from Python using Notepad++

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

I thought it might be time to start using `PowerShell` instead of `cmd`. I currently run Python scripts from Notepad++ with the following commnad:

`cmd /c cd &quot;$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)&quot; &amp;python -i &quot;$(FILE_NAME)&quot;`

How should I modify this to get the same behaviour in `PowerShell` please?

I tried

`powershell -noexit cd &quot;$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)&quot; &amp;python -i &quot;$(FILE_NAME)&quot;`

but I got an error about ampersands. I know very little about `PowerShell` or `cmd` in general - I just use them to run my Python scripts.

Comment: "I thought it might be time to start using PowerShell instead of cmd." Why?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Just open a cmd prompt and use the `python` command to execute your script. Are you trying to launch subprocesses?

Comment: The `&quot; &amp;` stuff definitely looks wrong. Are you really typing this verbatim into Notepad++?

Comment: It is triggered by a keyboard shortcut. I do it because NPP has a nasty habit of running scripts in a console opened from its own directory otherwise.

Comment: NPP added the quotes and  "escaped" the ampersand. Originally my code was: `cmd /c cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) & python -i $(FILE_NAME)`

Comment: You didn't answer my question about subprocesses but you say you don't know much about cmd or powershell. Why don't you just go to the directory of the script, hold down shift, right click --> "open a command window here" and then type `python myscript.py`?

Comment: I don't really know what a sub-process is, but  my use case is having a keyboard shortcut shortcut set up so I can easily run a python script from npp. It works as is, I just want to switch to using powershell instead of cmd. The ampersand in `powershell -noexit cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) & python -i $(FILE_NAME)` seems to be the problem.

Comment: So the real question here is "How to configure the directory NPP starts scripts in"?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging I found a solution:

`powershell -noexit cd '$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)'; python -i '$(FILE_NAME)'`

`PowerShell` seems to prefer single quotes for paths so I wrapped `$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` and `$(FILE_NAME)` in single quotes.

Also, `&` is replaced by `;` for multiple commands.

If there is a more "correct" way of doing this, please let me know.